# Java Scanner hasNext() skips empty lines

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The log file I want to work with is tab-separated and looks like this:

```
2019-06-06 10:01:02     1.0
2019-06-06 10:25:12 100.0
2019-06-06 11:02:32     2.0
```

I use the following code to scan through the file:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FirstTry {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String fileName = "LogFile.csv";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try
        {
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while (inputStream.hasNext()){
                String data = inputStream.nextLine();
                String[] values = data.split("\\t");
                System.out.println(values[0] + "    " + values[1]);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The line

```
System.out.println(values[0] + "    " + values[1]);
```

prints the following, working output:

```
2019-06-06 10:01:02    
2019-06-06 10:25:12    100.0
2019-06-06 11:02:32
```

but

```
System.out.println(values[0] + "    " + values[2]);
```

prints:

```
2019-06-06 10:01:02    1.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Why is this exceptions raised vor `values[2]` and not `values [1]`?

Edit:
Sublime Text Screenshot of the LogFile with the Tabs (5 in total) marked:
[image]

Edit 2:

```
String[] values = data.split("\\t+");
System.out.println(values[0] + "    " + values[1]);
```

prints:

```
2019-06-06 10:01:02    1.0
2019-06-06 10:25:12    100.0
2019-06-06 11:02:32    2.0
```

`System.out.println(values[0] + "    " + values[2]);`results in an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Is there really a tab between the date and time?

Comment: Are you sure there is a tab (as @RobAu said)? This would be the only explanation.

Comment: I Edited the Question and posted a Screenshot of the LogFile.

Comment: Try splitting on `\\t+` to handle multiple consecutive tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result of `String[] values = data.split("\\t");`

> 1: ["2019-06-06 10:01:02", "", "1.0"]
>   2: ["2019-06-06 10:25:12", "100.0"]
>   3: ["2019-06-06 11:02:32 ", "", "2.0"]

Note that double tabulation will split to an empty String.
On line 2 there is a single tabulation which results in an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` because values does not have a third value.

As mentionned by @Thilo, a split on `"\\t+"` should fix your problem

Comment: I see why the exception was raised. "\\t+" puts all values (100,1.0,2.0) into value[1].

Answer (score 0):

The problem as stated by other is that there are empty entries in the array i.e.

> ["2019-06-06 10:01:02", "", "1.0"]

So you need to delete all such entries. Using Java 8 this can be done like:

```
// You have the "values" array now do this...
String[] correctValues = Arrays.stream(values)
            .filter(value ->
                    value != null && value.length() > 0
            )
            .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
// Rest of the code ...
```